# upgraded maven pom.xml from java 8 to 13. how can i run upgraded maven project on both java 8 and 13 installed machines

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, javac, java-13

When am trying to maven build to create a fat jar an upgraded project in java 8 installed machine getting following error

`Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project : Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 13 -> [Help 1]`

Comment: You need to use toolchains for compiling the code on both the versions individually, see [this official example](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/module-info.html).

Comment: You can simply compile with JDK 8 and you can run on JDK 13 ... ? apart from that as already mentioned you can compile with JDK 13 (using --release 13) and try to run on JDK 8 ..

Answer (score 1):

You can't compile against a target Java version of 13 when using Java 8. Either upgrade your JDK, or change your target compiler level to 1.8.